# GPUImageUIElement -> GPUImageView doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, gpuimage

I'm trying to capture fullscreen video, but first of all wanna capture some simple view. Get image from UIView and produce below view. Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
    label.text = @"fds";
    [self.view addSubview:label];

    handleUiElem = [[GPUImageUIElement alloc] initWithView:label];

    CGRect frame = label.frame;
    frame.origin.y += 100;
    outView = [[GPUImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    outView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:outView];

    [handleUiElem addTarget:outView];
    [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.2 target:self selector:@selector(update:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES] fire];
}

- (void)update:(id)timer
{
    [handleUiElem updateUsingCurrentTime];
}
```

But as are result I get black view instead of text in label. What I'm doing wrong?
[image]

Comment: So did you resolve this problem?

Comment: Yes. This is cause background of the label when render is black, so I do not see black text. If you will render white text color, you will see some result. @sky1224

Comment: Now I'm rechecking.. And can you please check my issue case and help me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29442621/gpuimageuielement-blendfilter-moviewriter-issue? I think the case is the same as this, but even I used the updateUsingCurrentTime, I can't get any video, rather the project crashed. Please help me.

Comment: I got full screen video, Thanks for your advice!